# jQuery Filtering and Searching Array with Objects

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to solve my problem...

First I am populating my array called sourceArray via an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/WebService/getRegistrants?url=' + url + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&token=' + projectsArray[$("#dropdown").val()].apiToken,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var source = [];

                $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/WebService/getRegistrant?token=' + projectsArray[$("#dropdown").val()].apiToken + '&registrantId=' + value.registrantId,
                        type: "GET",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data2) {



                            sourceArray.push({ registrationDate: data2.registrationDate.split("T")[0], source: data2.sourceType.sourceType });



                        }
                    });

                });

            }

        });
```

My sourceArray returns a non-unique array with 2 objects for each item registrationDate and source:

```
{registrationDate: "2018-07-04", source: “New”}, {registrationDate: "2018-07-04", source: “New”}, {registrationDate: "2018-07-04", source: “Old”}, {registrationDate: "2018-07-03", source: “New”}, {registrationDate: "2018-07-03", source: “Old”}, {registrationDate: "2018-07-03", source: “Old”}
```

Now that I got everything I need from the ajax call, I do a loop but not with the data, I am looping between date ranges:

```
for (var d = new Date(startDate.replace("-", "/")); d <= now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {

            var year = d.getFullYear();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();

            if (month.toString().length < 2) month = '0' + month;

            if (day.toString().length < 2) day = '0' + day;

            console.log([year, month, day].join('-'));

        }
```

Now What I am trying to do is get total of source "New" Where the registrationDate = console.log([year, month, day].join('-')), if the dates do not equal, then return 0.

I really hope this makes sense. My question is how would I filter my array to get the total number of "New" source?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
var find = $.grep(names, function(v) {
    return v.registrationDate === [year, month, day].join('-') && v.source === "New";
});

console.log(find.length);
```